# Strange behaviour mounting Windows drive in docker container

Tags: docker

I am using Docker with Windows 10 and trying to mount a folder in my `D:` drive to a container. This should be possible with the latest version.

I have already shared my `D:` drive in "Settings -> Shared Drives"

If I execute this in docker:

```
docker run --rm -v /D:/data alpine ls /data
```

Then it correctly lists the files and folders in the root of my `D:` drive. This proves that it can see my `D:` drive and mount it.

If I execute this:

```
docker run --rm -v D:/:/data alpine ls /data
```

Then it correctly also lists the files and folders in the root of my `D:` drive. Proving that the command can handle different syntax for the `D:` drive.

However if I do any of these:

```
docker run --rm -v D:/M3:/data alpine ls /data
docker run --rm -v D:/M3/:/data alpine ls /data
docker run --rm -v /D/M3:/data alpine ls /data
docker run --rm -v /D/M3/:/data alpine ls /data
docker run --rm -v D:\M3:/data alpine ls /data
docker run --rm -v D:\M3\:/data alpine ls /data
docker run --rm -v D:\M3:/data alpine ls /data
```

They will not list files in the folder `D:\M3`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you say you can see the content of D/ in /data, do you see /data/M3/* in there?

Comment: Yes, it will display `M3` in there if I list `/data` when attached to `/D`

Comment: But will it display `M3` *content* though? `ls /data/M3`?

Comment: Good question, I've just checked and no it won't. I've done the classic security check and granted "Everyone" full access btw.

Comment: So if it does not, that would explain why mounting directly `/D/M3` shows nothing in `/data/`.

Comment: Yes it would. What then would explain not seeing a list for `ls /data/M3` though? I'm still stuck.

Comment: I suspect some kind of attribute ("recursive"?) is missing on the ""Settings -> Shared Drives" of the Hyper-V VM.

Comment: Settings -> Shared Drives is a setting in the docker task tray on windows, and there are no options other than entering credentials to connect as  unfortunately.

Comment: I hope this is not issue 21909 https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21909#issuecomment-221698245

Comment: I am checking https://forums.docker.com/c/docker-for-windows right now

Comment: Just in case, can you `docker run` it with the `--privileged` option?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I've found this open issue which seems to be the same problem I am experiencing https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25232

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't have VirtualBox installed at all? (since it is not compatible with the Hyper-V service)

Comment: No I don't have VirtualBox installed. I rebuilt my PC very recently so very little is installed.

Comment: Maybe it is still a permission issue (even with your previuis "Everyone" full access setting): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/

Comment: I remember Windows not allowing shares with full access for everyone, but only through an account with password. May be that has an effect here?

Comment: I don't think it is permission related. My gut instinct is that docker is creating a hidden volume. File aren't visible the other way round either i.e. running this: `docker run --privileged --rm -v /D/:/data alpine touch /data/hello.txt` - I can't then see hello.txt in windows and I've got full Administrator access. But it shows up in a listing if I request one through docker.

Comment: No: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/ is still relevant: "Docker for Windows is unable to re-verify the credentials when it attempts to remount the drives"

Comment: I've tried a local user with administrator rights already. I'm not in C:\Users so the specially protected filers/folders thing shoudn't be an issue.

Comment: If I create a local user and log in as that user, it works. So this seems to be an issue with Windows Domain accounts.

Comment: That seems coherent with what I remembered from the type of account allowed to accessed a shared path on Windows.

Comment: I have updated the relevant issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25232#issuecomment-244359414

Comment: I just saw this (I am subscribed to this issue ;) )

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance btw!

Comment: No problem, let's hope somebody can help explaining this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old thread, but I'm adding my answer here for anyone else facing the same issue. I recently started using Windows and struggled a bit to get Docker working for WSL.

```
-v //d/host/folder:/container/folder
```

This works both on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Windows PowerShell

Comment: I think this has been addressed by the docker team now with both some bug fixes and better user experience. The thing to be aware of is that this creates a share on your PC which is then accessible over a network which may or may not be a good thing.